# CMakeLists. How to add -fpermissive flag for specific dir with header files

Tags: c++, c, cmake, esp32

I have a project each I writing in C++. In this project I also use proto-c to generate header and source files (yes, this is mismatched and I would like it to stay that way it is possible ).
When I have tried compile the project a get error with -fpermissive flag, because some code in generated files it has wirtied in C. I want to deactivate this error using CMakeList, but simply add function `add_compile_options(-fpermissive)` to CMakeLists.txt not works.
Below I present for you simplified tree each is part of project. This files is a `component` in IDF enviroment and another CMakeLists

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── parser.hpp
├── proto
│   ├── configuration.proto
│   ├── timestamp.proto
│   ├── units.proto
├── protobuf-c
│   ├── configuration.pb-c.c
│   ├── timestamp.pb-c.c
│   ├── units.pb-c.c
├── protobuf-h
│   ├── configuration.pb-c.h
│   ├── timestamp.pb-c.h
│   ├── units.pb-c.h
├── parser.cpp
└── README.md
```

And content of CMakeLists.txt

```
idf_component_register(SRCS "parser.cpp"
        "protobuf-c/timestamp.pb-c.c"
        "protobuf-c/units.pb-c.c"
        "protobuf-c/configuration.pb-c.c"
        INCLUDE_DIRS "."  "include" "protobuf-h"
        REQUIRES protobuf-c )

add_compile_options(-fpermissive) // not working
```

Comment: Header files doesn't have compiler options, since you never compile them separately. Do you mean that every source file that include the header file should have that option when being built?

Comment: And if the problem comes from the C source files (and not the header files) then perhaps build the C source files into a separate library, for which you can set the compiler option for that library target.

Comment: Alternatively, you could find a newer version of the library you're using, where the problems hopefully have been fixed. Or fix the errors yourself.

Comment: Problem comes form header file. It has some macro which  try to do not allowed conversion, int to enum,  but I need this macro to initialize structure, that's cause error. I also can switch to newer version or protoc (from google) but actualy I have huge pice of code has wrote by someone and I want to use it, and those code using generated file by proto-c (c library). If it will be impossible, wait for me long job

Comment: Converting an `int` to an `enum` is not a problem in C. Perhaps you could disable only that single error or warning? Considering that you talk about `-fpermissive` I assume you're using either GCC or Clang? Then please read their documentation about options available to disable specific errors or warnings.

Comment: Offtopic: Why you have C files of protobuf at all? Is this generated by protobuf? If yes why not generate C++ files?

Comment: I use xtensa-esp32s3-elf-gcc and xtensa-esp32s3-elf-g++. If I know how can I disable this single error I will do. I  thought , I should I use -fpermissive in CMakeList. 
@MarekR I wrote about it above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may set compiler flags and other options via **target**, which is created by
`idf_component_register` command. The name of the target is contained in the `COMPONENT_LIB` variable. E.g.:

```
target_compile_options(${COMPONENT_LIB} PRIVATE -fpermissive)
```

Make sure to place that line **after** the call to `idf_component_register`.

This method is described in the ESP32 documentation: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#controlling-component-compilation

Comment: Yes, this was that I need it. thx